# Firebase access is not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So the thing is i followed all the steps in my Firebase setup and stuff but the control is not moving in my `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method. The screen just freezes and nothing happens other than the `progressBar` going in circles.

Here is my gradle build.app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.parma.gareebcalculator"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is my code:-

```
public class RegsiterPage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private EditText userName;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private EditText repassword;
    private Button signUp;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_regsiter_page);

        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameid);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailid);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordid);
        repassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.repasswordid);
        signUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupid);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarid);
        // Used to intialize the firebase object and register the user on the server:-
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        signUp.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    //Email constraints:-
    //To check whether the entered email is of correct format:
    private boolean isValidEmail(String email)
    {
        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //Username constraints:-
    //To check whether the given username only contains letters or digits:
    private boolean userNameCheck(String name){
        if(Character.isDigit(name.charAt(0))){
            return  false;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<name.length();i++){
            if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(name.charAt(i))){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean checkUserNameLength(String name){
        if(name.length()<8){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //Password constraints:-
    //To see whethter the password contains any special characters or not:
    private boolean checkSpecial(String pass){
        byte[] bytes = pass.getBytes();
        for(byte temp:bytes){
            if(temp>=33 && temp<=47){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    //To see whethter the password is containing both alphabets and numbers:
    private boolean checkPassword(String pass){
        if(pass.length()<8){
            return false;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<pass.length();i++){
            if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit((pass.charAt(i)))){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void onSignUp(){
        final String usernameString = userName.getText().toString().trim();
        final String emailString = email.getText().toString().trim();
        final String passwordString = password.getText().toString().trim();
        final String repasswordString = repassword.getText().toString().trim();

        /**If any of the either fields login or password are empty then the following couple actions might take place:-
         * Also if the passwords mismatch then the user will be denied a successfull registeration*/
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(usernameString)){
            userName.setError("Please enter Username");
            userName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(emailString)){
            email.setError("Please enter Email Id");
            email.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordString)){
            password.setError("Please enter Password");
            password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }if(TextUtils.isEmpty(repasswordString)){
            repassword.setError("Please Re-enter Password");
            repassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(!userNameCheck(usernameString)){
            userName.setError("Username can contain only alphabets or digits.Username cannot start with a number");
            userName.setText("");
            userName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(!checkUserNameLength(usernameString)){
            userName.setError("The username should atleast contain 8 charchacters");
            userName.setText("");
            userName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (userName.getText().toString().contains(" ")) {
            userName.setError("Spaces NOT Allowed");
            userName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(!isValidEmail(emailString)){
            email.setError("Incorrect Email format");
            email.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (!repasswordString.equals(passwordString)){
            //Toast.makeText(this,"Password Mismatch.Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            password.setGravity(10);
            password.setError("Passwords are incorrect");
            password.setText("");
            repassword.setText("");
            password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(!checkPassword(passwordString)){
            password.setError("The password should be alphanumeric and should be 8 characters long.No special symbols allowed");
            password.setText("");
            repassword.setText("");
            password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(!checkSpecial(passwordString)){
            password.setError("The password should not contain any special characters");
            password.setText("");
            repassword.setText("");
            password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        //If all, username,email,password and repassword have been entered then the following part takes place
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        /*Here the user is created using a password and email and addonCompleteListener is optional part which states what to be
         done when the user has successfully logged in*/
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailString,passwordString).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(RegsiterPage.this,"Registered Successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //To record the username in a the android application:
                    /*FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    if(user!=null){
                        UserProfileChangeRequest profile = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                .setDisplayName(usernameString)
                                .build();

                        user.updateProfile(profile).addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(RegsiterPage.this,"Awesome Profile Created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(RegsiterPage.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }*/
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginPage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegsiterPage.this,"You are already Registered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    userName.setText("");
                    email.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                    repassword.setText("");
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(RegsiterPage.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    userName.setText("");
                    email.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                    repassword.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == signUp){
            onSignUp();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:-

Here is my logcat:-

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.parma.gareebcalculator, PID: 3149
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzb(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzdd)' on a null object reference
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvv.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwc.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown
     Source)
at com.example.parma.gareebcalculator.RegsiterPage.onsignup(RegsiterPage.java:192)
at com.example.parma.gareebcalculator.RegsiterPage.onClick(RegsiterPage.java:241)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

> **Solution found**

**Solution**: if anyone comes along this..just do this...my entire code and everything was pitch perfect...but what was wrong was with my emulator...it was running on API 24...and this actually was untraceable due to the fact that the app only cashed but never said how....so just try changing the API to 26(worked for me)and use or create a new emulator

Comment: did you enable the Email signin method in your firebase console? Also add an onFailure callback along with the onComplete callback, that might give you an idea as to what's wrong

Comment: @Kushan yes i did...its still unclear so as to what's wrong

Comment: @Kushan .. thanks for reviewing my code sir..I got the solution it is stated in the edited description.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your mAuth is Null and thats the reason for this crash

Keep a check

```
  if(mAuth !=null){

  }
```

Comment: He's initializing it in onCreate

Comment: Guys ...you won't believe what went wrong..my entire code was perfect...but my emulator which was working on API 24 was not allowing me to connect with the firebase even though everything seemed right

Comment: Yes what it was ?

Comment: @ABDevelopers..I hope u got the answer

Comment: I was going to answer you that try real device. It wont work in emulator

Comment: Thanks though to review my code...this emulator BS was the last thing I tried and it luckily worked

Comment: A big facepalm from my end lol. Great, glad it works for you now, anyway when you do deploy it, change the security rules to proper ones :) and accept an answer so that others don't keep checking this thread

Comment: @Kushan can you suggest me some proper security parameters and also what do you mean accept an answer..i didn't follow that

Comment: Check out their docs, try using user wise security rules to minimise risk. There'll be a tick mark under all answers. Clicking that will accept the answer as the right answer